# Incomplete proof concerning eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, proof-writing

I solved this exercise, that is the exercise 5.B.11 of *Linear algebra done right, third edition* of Axler

> Let $V$ a complex vector space and $T\in\mathcal L(V)$, $p\in\mathcal P(\Bbb C)$ a polynomial and $\alpha\in\Bbb C$. Prove that $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of $p(T)$ if and only if $\alpha=p(\lambda)$ for some eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $T$.

for any polynomial of degree at least one. My problem is that I cannot see if the result holds (vacuously or not) when the polynomial is constant or zero.

If $V$ would be finite-dimensional I know that $T$ have at least one eigenvalue. My problem is that if $V$ is infinite-dimensional and $T$ injective then I dont see clearly if $T$ must have necessarily at least an eigenvalue.

By the other side it doesnt seems correct to assert that $\alpha=p(\lambda)$ when such $\lambda$ doesnt exists, that is, the statement dont seems to hold vacuously.

Can someone help me to clarify this question?

P.S.: I dont know exactly what tags I must use for this question.

Comment: Doesn't the problem say $p$ is a polynomial of degree at least $1$?

Comment: @egreg no. It just say any polynomial with complex coefficients. Specifically it says for $p\in\mathcal P(\Bbb C)$, that is the set of polynomials with complex coefficients (including the zero and the constant ones).

Comment: If $p$ is a constant (zero or not), then the statement says "$\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of (the linear map given by multiplying by) $p$ if and only if $\alpha$ equals (the number) $p$".

Comment: @Arthur I thought something like this but from the wording of the problem it seems ambiguous. It is possible to show that this holds vacuously using some formal definition of the statement?

Comment: @copper it says that $$\alpha\text{ is an eigenvalue of }p(T)\implies \alpha=p(\lambda)\text{ for some eigenvalue }\lambda\text{ of }T$$ for any polynomial $p$. But if $p=c$ then $p(T)=cI$, hence $c$ is an eigenvalue of $p(T)$, but this doesnt imply that $c=p(\lambda)$ because such $\lambda$ doesnt necessarily exists. And the reverse implication holds because $F\implies V$ is true.

Comment: @Masacroso: You are correct. I missed your point. Indeed my proof below depends on $\partial p \ge 1$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this issue, which is an error on my part. For the next edition of the book, I have changed the hypothesis so that $p$ is a nonconstant polynomial. There is no need to assume that $V$ is finite-dimensional for this exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having reviewed the chapter in question, I think you're right: this holds if the polynomial has degree $>0$, or you know there is an eigenvalue, but is not true in general if there is no eigenvalue and $p$ is constant: then we do have $\{ p(\lambda) \mid \lambda \text{ is an eval of } T \} = \emptyset $.

So the result holds if at least one of the following is true:

- $\deg{p}>0$.
- $V$ is finite-dimensional,
- or more generally, you know $T$ has an eigenvalue.

If none of these is true, the result may not hold.

Comment: The book proved that if $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex vector space then $T$ have at least an eigenvalue. But the exercise doesnt state that $V$ is finite dimensional, it just state that $V$ is a complex vector space.

Comment: @Chappers It's false that every endomorphism has an eigenvalue if the vector space is not finite dimensional.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I know. The forward shift is the typical example.

Comment: @Masacroso Hm. Having reviewed the chapter in question, I think you're right: this holds if the polynomial has degree $>0$, or you know there is an eigenvalue, but is not true in general if there is no eigenvalue and $p$ is constant.

Comment: Looking in the solutions manual, Axler has assumed the existence of an eigenvalue in his proof.

Comment: @Masacroso As I recall, at some point in the book (at the beginning of one of the chapters I think), Axler explicitly says something along the lines of "We will assume from here on that all vector spaces are finitely dimensional unless otherwise specified."

Comment: This makes sense because there's a very limited amount you can say about infinite dimensional vector spaces without using analysis (see functional analysis).

Comment: @ChristianSykes I dont see it and indeed it doesnt make so much sense because for every theorem and exercise it is explicitly stated what is the dimensionality of the vector spaces involved. If it would be assumed finite dimension, then why explicitly state it arbitrarily some times? Moreover: in many exercise if the dimensionality is not stated in general it holds regardless of the dimension of the space.

Comment: @Masacroso From the Chapter 5 (Eignevalues and Eigenvectors) front matter on page 75 of the 2nd edition: "Now we begin our investigation of linear maps from a vector space to itself. ... Most of the key results in this area do not hold for infinite-dimensional vector spaces, so we work only on finite-dimensional vector spaces. ... Thus we make the
following assumption: Recall that F denotes R or C. Let’s agree that for the rest of the book V will denote a finite-dimensional, nonzero vector space over F."

Comment: Possibly this was changed in the 3rd edition.

Comment: @ChristianSykes this definetively was changed in the third edition, at least I dont found anything like this, but at the start of part $5$ is stated that the assumptions are that $\Bbb F$ denotes $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ and that $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb F$. No mention to it dimensionality. This seems just a little typo in the exercise (that is present in the second edition) when writing the third edition.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem solved by the author, there is a typo in the exercise and he has stated in [errata](https://linear.axler.net/LADRErrataThird.html) that the polynomial is nonconstant.